# How to use httpcontext on a given string URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use httpcontext on a given string

ex:

I have this

```
string url = "https://subdomain.domain.com/link1/";
```

And I want to be able to retreive those following value from the string

```
Console.Write("<br/>Host " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host);
Console.Write("<br/>Authority: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority);
Console.Write("<br/>Port: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port);
Console.Write("<br/>AbsolutePath: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
Console.Write("<br/>ApplicationPath: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
Console.Write("<br/>AbsoluteUri: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
Console.Write("<br/>PathAndQuery: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How is an `HttpContext` instance related to an URL in a string?

Comment: Are you trying to split an URL into its parts? You could use [the `Uri` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @UweKeim for the answer.

I can definitely do that by using [the Uri class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri).

Here's the sample of code for those who need it:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://subdomain.domain.com/link1/");        

Console.WriteLine($"AbsolutePath: {uri.AbsolutePath}");
Console.WriteLine($"AbsoluteUri: {uri.AbsoluteUri}");
Console.WriteLine($"DnsSafeHost: {uri.DnsSafeHost}");
Console.WriteLine($"Fragment: {uri.Fragment}");
Console.WriteLine($"Host: {uri.Host}");
Console.WriteLine($"HostNameType: {uri.HostNameType}");
Console.WriteLine($"IdnHost: {uri.IdnHost}");
Console.WriteLine($"IsAbsoluteUri: {uri.IsAbsoluteUri}");
Console.WriteLine($"IsDefaultPort: {uri.IsDefaultPort}");
Console.WriteLine($"IsFile: {uri.IsFile}");
Console.WriteLine($"IsLoopback: {uri.IsLoopback}");
Console.WriteLine($"IsUnc: {uri.IsUnc}");
Console.WriteLine($"LocalPath: {uri.LocalPath}");
Console.WriteLine($"OriginalString: {uri.OriginalString}");
Console.WriteLine($"PathAndQuery: {uri.PathAndQuery}");
Console.WriteLine($"Port: {uri.Port}");
Console.WriteLine($"Query: {uri.Query}");
Console.WriteLine($"Scheme: {uri.Scheme}");
Console.WriteLine($"Segments: {string.Join(", ", uri.Segments)}");
Console.WriteLine($"UserEscaped: {uri.UserEscaped}");
Console.WriteLine($"UserInfo: {uri.UserInfo}");
```